# Use different font for different languages in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, android-fonts

I use a custom font for EditText fields, but the font I use has only English characters. When I type in a different language the application uses the default Android font for that language.

Is it possible to have a one font for English input and another for a different language?

To set the EditText font I do:

```
mFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "eraslght.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(mFont1 );
```

Answer (score 3):

What if you used strings.xml like the following:

```
mFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), getString(R.strings.button_font));
textView.setTypeface(mFont1 );
```

and in strings.xml just put the relevant path as a string...

Answer (score 1):

You can check what language is currently set in system and set different fonts for them.

```
mFont1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "eraslght.ttf");
if (Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() == "en") {
    textView.setTypeface(mFont1);
} else {
    textView.setTypeface(mFont2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, bu it doesn't do the trick because the font should be depend on the keyboard language and not the display language...